# Spacing for badges in the signature

Tags: discussion, bug, design

[image]

The spacing should be smaller between the badge color and the number of badges than between two color-number groups.

As it is, it looks like there are `96` bronze badges rather than `153`.

Comment: Never mind the 96 bronze badges, what about the 32.6k gold badges! ;)

Comment: @falstro I have no problem with that!  (It seems to be my signature used as example)

Comment: Can I just take a minute to say that AviationSE officially has the coolest custom badges? You could say this site is really... TAKING OFF!! *ba dumm tssss*